# std::bad_alloc when inserting into std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, dictionary, bad-alloc

I'm sometimes getting an std::bad_alloc for the following code:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<chash, block_extended_info> map_type;
map_type m_foo; 

// the transgressor:
auto r = m_foo.insert(map_type::value_type(id, bei));
```

It happens some of the time while running test cases that use the method containing that line, and other times it doesn't.  I had changed the code to use `m_foo[id] = bei`, which caused it to stop happening for one compilation, but then when I recompiled again it failed, so I changed it to the above, which continued to fail.  Clearly the issue is deeper than that.

I am fairly sure it's not a matter of running out of memory since I have `top` running while the test cases are running and it doesn't get anywhere near filling up the memory.

What may be causing the std::bad_alloc?  What in the details of `chash` and `block_extended_info` may be causing this?  Objects of those types are copied and passed around all over the place in other parts of the code and that doesn't cause any issues.

Here's the definition of `chash`:

```
class chash {
  char data[32];
};
```

And the following is everything required to define `block_extended_info`:

```
class csignature {
  chash c, r;
};
enum foob { /* ... */ };
class ct {
  uint64_t a, b;
  foob c;
};
typedef boost::variant< /* structs with ints, maps, vectors of ints */ > txin_v;
typedef boost::variant< /* similar structs */ > txout_target_v;
struct tx_out {
    uint64_t a;
    txout_target_v b;
};
class transaction_prefix
{
public:
  size_t   version;
  uint64_t unlock_time;
  std::vector<uint8_t> extra;

protected:
  std::vector<txin_v> a;
  std::vector<tx_out> b;
  std::vector<ct> c;
  std::vector<ct> d;
};
class transaction: public transaction_prefix
{
public:
  std::vector<std::vector<csignature> > signatures;
};
struct block_header
{
  uint8_t  major_version;
  uint8_t  minor_version;
  uint64_t timestamp;
  chash    prev_id;
  uint32_t nonce;
};
struct block: public block_header
{
  transaction miner_tx;
  std::vector<chash> tx_hashes;
  uint16_t food_id;
  csignature food_sig;
};
struct block_extended_info
{
  block    bl;
  uint64_t height;
  size_t   block_cumulative_size;
  uint64_t cumulative_difficulty;
  uint64_t already_generated_coins;
};
```

Stepping around the relevant area in gdb, here are the latest few lines that lead up to the bad_alloc:

```
cryptonote::transaction::transaction(cryptonote::transaction const&) () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:313
313       { this->_M_impl._M_finish =
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
91      : _Tp_alloc_type(__a), _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0)
168       { return __n != 0 ? _M_impl.allocate(__n) : 0; }
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
181     this->_M_impl._M_start = this->_M_allocate(__n);
182     this->_M_impl._M_finish = this->_M_impl._M_start;
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
310       vector(const vector& __x)
117     __uninit_copy(__first, __last, __result);
cryptonote::tx_out* std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<cryptonote::tx_out const*, std::vector<cryptonote::tx_out, std::allocator<cryptonote::tx_out> > >, cryptonote::tx_out*>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<cryptonote::tx_out const*, std::vector<cryptonote::tx_out, std::allocator<cryptonote::tx_out> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<cryptonote::tx_out const*, std::vector<cryptonote::tx_out, std::allocator<cryptonote::tx_out> > >, cryptonote::tx_out*) ()
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:68
68          __uninit_copy(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
74            for (; __first != __last; ++__first, ++__cur)
83      }
cryptonote::transaction::transaction(cryptonote::transaction const&) () at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:313
313       { this->_M_impl._M_finish =
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
91      : _Tp_alloc_type(__a), _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0)
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
168       { return __n != 0 ? _M_impl.allocate(__n) : 0; }
101     if (__n > this->max_size())
104     return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
181     this->_M_impl._M_start = this->_M_allocate(__n);
182     this->_M_impl._M_finish = this->_M_impl._M_start;
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
310       vector(const vector& __x)
74            for (; __first != __last; ++__first, ++__cur)
71        _ForwardIterator __cur = __result;
75      { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
748     ++_M_current;
74            for (; __first != __last; ++__first, ++__cur)
313       { this->_M_impl._M_finish =
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
91      : _Tp_alloc_type(__a), _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0)
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
168       { return __n != 0 ? _M_impl.allocate(__n) : 0; }
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
181     this->_M_impl._M_start = this->_M_allocate(__n);
182     this->_M_impl._M_finish = this->_M_impl._M_start;
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
310       vector(const vector& __x)
74            for (; __first != __last; ++__first, ++__cur)
570   class transaction: public transaction_prefix
313       { this->_M_impl._M_finish =
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
91      : _Tp_alloc_type(__a), _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0)
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
168       { return __n != 0 ? _M_impl.allocate(__n) : 0; }
101     if (__n > this->max_size())
104     return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
181     this->_M_impl._M_start = this->_M_allocate(__n);
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
181     this->_M_impl._M_start = this->_M_allocate(__n);
182     this->_M_impl._M_finish = this->_M_impl._M_start;
183     this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = this->_M_impl._M_start + __n;
310       vector(const vector& __x)
74            for (; __first != __last; ++__first, ++__cur)
101     if (__n > this->max_size())
75      { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
646       { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
91      : _Tp_alloc_type(__a), _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0)
168       { return __n != 0 ? _M_impl.allocate(__n) : 0; }
101     if (__n > this->max_size())
102       std::__throw_bad_alloc();
```

Comment: `size_t` is implementation defined. Why dont use `uint64_t` as with other fields?

Comment: @UmNyobe: Good question. I inherited that part of the code so left it as-is. Could that be the issue?

Comment: _@xpbcreator_ It's actually impossible to diagnose the problem with the code context you give. I's suspect the error occurs elsewhere, or because of an uninitialized variable, or otherwise undefined behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: So it's likely some part of the code is stepping over some memory and then causing this weird behavior?

Comment: The edit code portion doesnt match the code you originally posted. It match `transaction` copy constructor. And `transaction_prefix` is quite an ugly class.

Comment: @xpbcreator Well, you are inheriting from classes that do not have virtual destructors.  If your code is doing anything like this: `Base* b = new Derived;  ... delete b;` then you will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: πάνταῥεῖ was right: the code calling that function was a mess and it was using an invalidated iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As πάντα ῥεῖ suspected, the problem was elsewhere.

The code I listed was in a function called `add_block_as_invalid(...)`. The call site looked something like this:

```
// parameter, iterators into m_alternative_chains
std::list<blocks_ext_by_hash::iterator>& alt_chain; 

for(auto alt_ch_iter = alt_chain.begin(); 
    alt_ch_iter != alt_chain.end(); 
    alt_ch_iter++) 
{
    // ....
    auto ch_ent = *alt_ch_iter;
    // ....
    m_alternative_chains.erase(ch_ent);

    for(auto alt_ch_to_orph_iter = ++alt_ch_iter; 
        alt_ch_to_orph_iter != alt_chain.end(); 
        alt_ch_to_orph_iter++) 
    {
        add_block_as_invalid((*alt_ch_iter)->second, (*alt_ch_iter)->first);
        m_alternative_chains.erase(*alt_ch_to_orph_iter);
    }
}
```

The call to `add_block_as_invalid` kept dereferencing `alt_ch_iter`, which had already been erased.